# What's the fastest way to store a stock's ticker symbol and name, for 'cashtags' on a spring boot backend?

Tags: database, spring-boot, sqlite, elasticsearch, h2

Update: It was solved! I will just keep it in memory. 10,000 strings is not that much to keep loaded all the time. I was overthinking it

I want to implement cashtags, similar to twitter hashtags, but when you use $ instead of #, it'll look up a ticker symbol(Similar to StockTwits too). To do this, I'm considering having a list of all ticker symbols on the backend on a local database, but I don't know if that'd be the best solution. Since I will need to constantly search this list, it needs to be very fast, for that reason, and to prevent massive amounts of queries to MySQL(or Redis), I'm thinking it might be better to store it locally (or using Elasticsearch?).

I will need to check if the ticker exists every time a user makes a post containing a cashtag(which will happen often), as well as every time someone makes a search for the symbol. Once I know the ticker exists, I will bring the rest of its information from Redis. There are around 10,000 stock symbols that will need to be saved and constantly searched through, and every time a person looks up a cashtag, it will bring up the company name, which will preferably be saved with it.

I'm wondering what's the best way to store the stock symbols, and the corresponding company name? Can anyone explain the best local database that I should use or if something else like elasticsearch would be better, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store in the database and use some Map implementation as a cache.
You do not have so many tickers so it will fit in memory.

As long you will keep immutable data you do not need to sync between instances.

Comment: So you believe I could just store it in a CSV or anything, and just keep it all in the server's memory?  You know what, you're absolutely right, 10000 strings will come out to a fraction of a gig. The data is mostly immutable, as new stock tickers are introduced not very often, so I can come up with another solution to add more. Thanks, I was overthinking it!